# Remotely debug Linux Kernel from Windows?

Tags: linux-kernel, vmware, eclipse-cdt, remote-debugging

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to remotely debug the Linux kernel running under VMWare (and if so, if there's a way to do it in Windows since linux kind of scares me...). Both are x86. I know VMWare has support for this (I saw a post about remote debugging via gdb), but if there was a way to do it from Windows (i.e. Eclipse CDT or something) that'd be awesome.

Thanks!
-Robert

Comment: "debug the Linux kernel" and "linux kind of scares me" in the same sentence? Really?

Comment: If Linux scares you, you shouldn't be doing kernel debugging. What specifically do you want to debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a thread where someone got 95% of the way here: http://communities.vmware.com/thread/236251. The one part he's missing is that the source files can't be found, but CDT supports setting a source path different from the symbol file. A bit of messing around and it seems to be working (i.e. I can set breakpoints, see the entire address space, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

You're not going to debug the Linux kernel (particularly remotely) using anything but `gdb` with { `kdb` | `kgdb` } extensions in-kernel, unless you write your own debug hooks.

Comment: CDB can access GDB remotely if gdbserver is running... I'm just wondering if anyone has this working?

Answer (score 0):

[According to Linus](http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Kernel/linus-im-a-bastard-speech.html), he would prefer if you do not use a kernel debugger, even on Linux. Good luck getting one to work from Windows :)

Granted, this posting is from several years ago. Maybe he has changed his mind since then???

Comment: Okay, so linus is an ***wipe. How does this at all address the question? There are several active linux kernel debuggers and kgdb hooks are now in the kernel source.

Comment: Um, Linus Torvalds is quite far from any derogatory term you could come up with about him. Please get off SO for a second and recompose yourself.

Comment: Dude, did you read the post? He comes across as an elitist bastard

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend debugging one Linux VM from another linux VM, if you only have one machine running Windows available.

You're going to have enough difficulty just getting that working, without throwing in something that is as unsupported and untested as what you're currently asking for.